# Get indexed Vector in Vertex AI Vector Search

Tags: embedding, google-cloud-ml, vertex

Simple question : How to get the ids of the indexed vectors in  Vertex AI Vector Search ?

I curretly keep all of this data in a separate table when I manually enrich the index. But at the end, this simple feature would be more precise than my table

Thank you

Comment: Did you find an answer? Same question